# Packaging node webkit application trouble

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, node-webkit-agent

I want to package a nodewebkit application for windows. I followed this tutorial https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps#mac-os-x

I got the .exe file, but can't execute it.

Answer (score 0):

First, copy app.nw file into folder where nw.exe exists. Then you can try following command in cmd:

path_to_folder_which_contains_nw.exe>copy nw.exe+app.nw app.exe
You will get the message "1 file copied" after successful app.exe created. It will create a single executable file but it will not run outside that folder. Then you can use windows installer like iexplore.exe(defualt windows installer) to create installer exe.

Answer (score 0):

The exe file alone will not work. You need to [add the 'nw.pak' file](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps#windows-1):

> And please note that the nw.pak file must also be in the same
>   directory with the app file, otherwise you would expect blank page for
>   some features.

As well as a [few DLLs](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps#windows-2):

> The nw.pak and icudt.dll must be shipped along with nw.exe, the former
>   one contains important javascript lib files, and the latter one is a
>   important network library.
>
> ffmpegsumo.dll are media library, if you want to use  and
>    tag, or other media related features, you should ship it.
>
> libEGL.dll and libGLESv2.dll are used for WebGL and GPU acceleration,
>   you had better ship them. And D3DCompiler_43.dll and d3dx9_43.dll as
>   well if you want to make sure WebGL works on more hardware. These 2
>   files are from DirectX redistributable.

Eventually, It should look something like this:
[image]

My recommendation is that you won't do it manually. Instead use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to build the exe file. To get started, use [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and [generator-node-webkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-node-webkit) for a basic project layout and build script.

Than, making win executable (or mac) is easy as:

```
grunt dist-mac
grunt dist-win
```